# Hadoop : ssh: Could not resolve hostname name: Name or service not known

Tags: hadoop, ssh

There were some external jars path to be added to the hadoop classpath. After running start-dfs.sh, I found these errors. Hadoop runs normally if I remove the classpath from hadoop-env.sh file.  I have also set `HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native"` and`export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR="/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/"` in the hadoop-env.sh file.

```
[main]]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [main]]: Name or service not known
using: ssh: Could not resolve hostname using: Name or service not known
14:48:34.392: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 14:48:34.392: Name or service not known
hadoop: ssh: Could not resolve hostname hadoop: Name or service not known
14:48:34.392: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 14:48:34.392: Name or service not known
UserGroupInformation: ssh: Could not resolve hostname usergroupinformation: Name or service not known
KerberosName: ssh: Could not resolve hostname kerberosname: Name or service not known
hadoop.security.token.service.use_ip: ssh: Could not resolve hostname hadoop.security.token.service.use_ip: Name or service not known
cacheTimeout=300000;: ssh: Could not resolve hostname cachetimeout=300000;: Name or service not known
Group: ssh: Could not resolve hostname group: Name or service not known
[main]]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [main]]: Name or service not known
[[DEBUG]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [[debug]: Name or service not known
login: ssh: Could not resolve hostname login: Name or service not known
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
Using: ssh: Could not resolve hostname using: Name or service not known
[main]]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [main]]: Name or service not known
warningDeltaMs=5000: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warningdeltams=5000: Name or service not known
UserGroupInformation: ssh: Could not resolve hostname usergroupinformation: Name or service not known
user:UnixPrincipal:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname user:unixprincipal:: Name or service not known
[[DEBUG]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [[debug]: Name or service not known
UserGroupInformation: ssh: Could not resolve hostname usergroupinformation: Name or service not known
[main]]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [main]]: Name or service not known
[[DEBUG]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [[debug]: Name or service not known
UserGroupInformation: ssh: Could not resolve hostname usergroupinformation: Name or service not known
name: ssh: Could not resolve hostname name: Name or service not known
"username": ssh: Could not resolve hostname "username": Name or service not known
entry:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname entry:: Name or service not known
from: ssh: Could not resolve hostname from: Name or service not known
PrivilegedAction: ssh: Could not resolve hostname privilegedaction: Name or service not known
subject.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname subject.: Name or service not known
[[DEBUG]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [[debug]: Name or service not known
UserGroupInformation: ssh: Could not resolve hostname usergroupinformation: Name or service not known
14:48:34.393: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 14:48:34.393: Name or service not known
[[DEBUG]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [[debug]: Name or service not known
user:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname user:: Name or service not known
externally: ssh: Could not resolve hostname externally: Name or service not known
UserGroupInformation: ssh: Could not resolve hostname usergroupinformation: Name or service not known
is: ssh: Could not resolve hostname is: Name or service not known
UGI: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ugi: Name or service not known
managed: ssh: Could not resolve hostname managed: Name or service not known
UserGroupInformation: ssh: Could not resolve hostname usergroupinformation: Name or service not known
[main]]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [main]]: Name or service not known
loginUser:username: ssh: Could not resolve hostname loginuser:username: Name or service not known
[main]]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [main]]: Name or service not known
[[DEBUG]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [[debug]: Name or service not known
from:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf.run(GetConf.java:315): ssh: Could not resolve hostname from:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.getconf.run(getconf.java:315): Name or service not known
[[DEBUG]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [[debug]: Name or service not known
login: ssh: Could not resolve hostname login: Name or service not known
[[DEBUG]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname [[debug]: Name or service not known
commit: ssh: Could not resolve hostname commit: Name or service not known
keytab: ssh: Could not resolve hostname keytab: Name or service not known
logged: ssh: Could not resolve hostname logged: Name or service not known
(auth:SIMPLE): ssh: Could not resolve hostname (auth:simple): Name or service not known
in: ssh: Could not resolve hostname in: Name or service not known
Assuming: ssh: Could not resolve hostname assuming: Name or service not known
User: ssh: Could not resolve hostname user: Name or service not known
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: I suggest you start from the beginning explaining exactly what steps got you to this point.

Comment: There were external jars path to be added to the hadoop classpath. After adding so, when I ran start-dfs.sh I found the error.

Comment: Did the cluster start before you added any JARs? `start-dfs` calls `ssh` on various components. Are you sure you didn't end up removing some quotes in that script, for example? Also, JARs are typically added per-application that needs them, or on the YARN classpath, not the Hadoop classpath.

Comment: The cluster did start before adding JARs. I have also added on yarn classpath. This is the classpath to external JARs :  `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/home/avinashshetty/jars/hibernate/:/home/avinashshetty/jars/* `

Comment: As mentioned, JARs shouldnt really be added for Hadoop to work. If you need them for any MapReduce,Spark,etc application, then there are separate classpath settings for those.